# PHP Laravel will deployment overwrite existing data

Tags: php, laravel

I want to deploy my Laravel application. I created some new Models and Migrations but I'm dreading that when I deploy the changes the existing data on the production site will be deleted, is that so? And how about the `.env` file with the DB settings?

Comment: Just export your data so that way if it all goes down the drain you can simply import that SQL file.

Comment: Are you deploy your site to Heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a backup of your production side, import it locally and run migration locally to test.
If possible, always make a backup of your production database before migrations.

Comment: Thanks! What about the `.env` file? any suggestions to that?

Comment: what do you mean by .env variables for db settings? I assume you have different environments in your project `dev`, `staging` and `prod`? the .env should have just the prod env variables where you deploy